# How do I prove that the limit of the sequence exists: $a_n = \frac1n +\frac 1{n+1} + \frac1{n+2} + \dots + \frac1{2n}$?

Tags: real-analysis

How do I prove that the limit of the sequence exists: $$a_n = \frac1n +\frac 1{n+1} + \frac1{n+2} + \dots + \frac1{2n}$$

I can find the limit as n goes to infinity, $\frac1{2n}$ goes to $0$, so the limit is $0$ right? But how do I prove that the limit exists? Do I have to use the $\varepsilon$ $\delta$ definition of a limit?

For part b) I have to show that the limit is less then $1$ but not less then $\frac12$, I thought the limit was $0$?

Comment: Note, that you add a lot of terms, so what you did in the first part does not suffice (there you just concluded that the smallest term tends to zero).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears from your question that you’ve misunderstood what you’re supposed to do. To make it clearer, sit down and calculate a few terms of your sequence:

$$\begin{align*}
a_1&=\frac11+\frac12=\frac32\\
a_2&=\frac12+\frac13+\frac14=\frac{13}{12}\\
a_3&=\frac13+\frac14+\frac15+\frac16=\frac{19}{20}\\
a_4&=\frac14+\frac15+\frac16+\frac17+\frac18=\frac{743}{840}
\end{align*}$$

The fact that the numbers $\frac1{2n}$ approach $0$ tells you nothing much about what the sequence $\langle a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots\rangle$ is doing.

You might notice that $a_1>a_2>a_3>a_4$. That suggests trying to show that the sequence is decreasing, meaning that $a_{n+1}<a_n$ for each $n$. The easiest way to do that is to show that $a_n-a_{n+1}>0$. What is $a_n-a_{n+1}$? It’s

$$\left(\frac1n+\frac1{n+1}+\ldots+\frac1{2n}\right)-\left(\frac1{n+1}+\ldots+\frac1{2n}+\frac1{2n+1}+\frac1{2n+2}\right)\;.\tag{1}$$

Now do a lot of cancelling and express the result as a single fraction; it will be easy to check that this fraction is positive.

Since the sequence is decreasing, and $a_3$ is clearly less than $1$, any limit must certainly be less than $1$. To show that the limit is not less than $\frac12$, think about the following questions:

- What is the smallest term in the sum for $a_n$?
- How many terms are there in the sum for $a_n$?

Comment: I understand it better now but what does the 1/(2n) at the end of the sequence represent and when you asked how many terms there are in the sum for an isn't that infinity because the sequence can go to infinity?

Comment: @idknuttin: No, $\frac1{2n}$ is the last term in the *finite* sum that is $a_n$. Look at the five examples in my answer: $a_4$, for instance, is the sum of just $5$ terms, $\frac14$ through $\frac18$. Here $n=4$, so the first term, $\frac1n$, is $\frac14$, and the last term, $\frac1{2n}$, is $\frac18$.

Comment: ok, so the smallest term in the sum for an is 1/(2n), I understand how the sum of an is finite when you choose n=1 or n=2 and so on but n can equal any number up to infinity? so how can you find the numer of terms in the sum?

Comment: How many terms do you see in the sum for $a_1$? For $a_2$? For $a_3$? For $a_4$? There’s a pretty clear pattern for you to guess, one that lets you express the number of terms in the sum for $a_n$ as a function of $n$. Once you guess it, you’ll have to explain why your guess is correct, but the first step is finding the pattern in the first place.

Comment: The number of terms in the sum is n+1, so is the smallest term in the sum 1/(n+1)?

Comment: @idknuttin: The number of terms is indeed $n+1$, but the $\frac1{n+1}$ is only the second term in the sum. What is the smallest one? We talked about it in earlier comments.

Comment: 1/(2n) would be the smallest term right?

Comment: @idknuttin: Yes, it would. $\frac1n$ is the largest, $\frac1{2n}$ is the smallest, and there are $n+1$ terms altogether.

Answer (score 4):

We deal with **existence** of the limit. Note that the $a_k$ are positive, Now we will show that $a_{n+1}\lt a_n$ for all $n$. This is straightforward, for
$$a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}-\frac{1}{n}\lt a_n,$$
because $\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}\lt \frac{2}{2n+1}\lt \frac{1}{n}$.

To finish, recall that a decreasing sequence which is bounded below has a limit.

Comment: As for the second part: the argument above shows that $(a_n)_n$ is decreasing, and you have $a_2 = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4} < 1$. Also, $a_n = \frac{1}{n}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n} > \frac{1}{2n}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n} = (n+1)\cdot \frac{1}{2n} > \frac{1}{2}$ for all $n$.

Comment: I'll delete my comment, as your latest edit gives the lower bound. However, for the upper bound it leaves open the probability that the limit be $1$, not *less* than one, as phrased.

Comment: I think it is best to leave the comment, it is valuable. The thing I have at the end is basically a remark, the post only deals fully with existence.

Comment: Ack. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 4):

Another point of view:

If you know about integration and Riemann sums, you can write your expression as
$$
\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{1+0/n}+\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{1+1/n}+\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{1+2/n}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{1+(n-1)/n}+\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{1+n/n},
$$
which is a Riemann sum for
$$
\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x}\,dx=\bigl[\log(1+x)\bigr]_0^1=\log2-\log1=\log2.
$$
Since the function $x\mapsto 1/(1+x)$ is continuous in $[0,1]$, we find that, as $n\to+\infty$,
$$
\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n}\to \int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x}\,dx=\log2\approx 0.69.
$$

Comment: log 2 = 0.301, ln 2 = 0.69?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, to me $\log=\log_e=\ln$.

Comment: why did you find the integral from 0 to 1? because it is also continous on and interval that is contained in [0,1] why does the interval [0,1] give you the limit of the sequence?

Comment: This is by the nature of [Riemann sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum), the general term for an integral over $[a,b]$ being $\Delta x f(a+k\Delta x)$, where $\Delta x=(b-a)/n$. With $b=1$, $a=0$ we get $\Delta x=1/n$ and $f(a+k\Delta x)=1/(1+k/n)$.