# $a_{n+1}\ge a_n$ for $a_n=\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{n+2}+\dots+\frac1{2n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, summation, induction, harmonic-numbers

Let $a_n = {1 \ \over n+1} +{1 \ \over n+2}+ \ldots\ +{1 \ \over 2n}. $
Prove that for $ n \ge\ 3 $ one has  $ a_{n+1}\ge\ a_n $. and based on this conclude that $ {a_{2019}}>{3 \over 5}$

I try
$ a_{n+1}- a_n  =  {1 \ \over n+2}+{1 \ \over n+3} +{1 \ \over n+4}+\ldots\ + {1 \ \over 2(n+1)} -  {1 \ \over n+1} -{1 \ \over n+2}-{1 \ \over n+3}-{1 \ \over n+4}- \ldots\ -{1 \ \over 2n}      $
$$  = {1 \ \over 2(n+1)}-{1 \ \over n+1}={1 \ \over (n+1)} \gt\ 0 $$

Comment: Compute $a_{n+1}-a_n$.

Comment: You have an error in simplifying $a_{n+1}-a_n$: it has three terms.

Comment: Some similar older questions: [Proving $\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n} > \frac{13}{24}$ for $n>1,n\in\Bbb N$ by Induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/508664) and [How do I prove that the limit of the sequence exists: $a_n = \frac1n +\frac 1{n+1} + \frac1{n+2} + \dots + \frac1{2n}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1484905).

Comment: And some general tips on searching: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Comment: Three terms : $\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}-\frac{1}{n+1}>0$

Comment: Also, in the last line it should be $\frac1{2(n+1)}-\frac1{n+1}=-\frac1{2(n+1)}<0$, so that with the correct sign of the difference the error might have been immediately evident.

Comment: Is this a question from an on-going contest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are done with $$a_{2019}>a_3={1\over 4}+{1\over 5}+{1\over 6}={37\over 60}>{3\over 5}$$

Answer (score 1):

Supppose $n \geq 3$.\begin{align*} a_{n+1} &= \frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{1}{n+3}+ \cdots + \frac{1}{2n+1} + \frac{1}{2n+2}  \\ & =\left(  \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2}+ \cdots + \frac{1}{2n-1} + \frac{1}{2n} \right) + \left( \frac{1}{2n+1} + \frac{1}{2n+2} - \frac{1}{n+1}   \right) \\ & = a_n + \left( \frac{1}{2n+1} + \frac{1}{2n+2} - \frac{1}{n+1} \right) \end{align*}
Observe $$ \frac{1}{2n+1} + \frac{1}{2n+2} - \frac{1}{n+1} > \frac{1}{2n+2} + \frac{1}{2n+2} - \frac{1}{n+1} =0$$
Thus $a_{n+1} \geq a_n$.

To prove $a_{2019} > \frac{3}{5}$, I recommended you to compute first few values of $\{a_n\}_{n \geq 3}$. Fortunately, at $n=3$ we have 
$$a_{2019} \geq a_3 = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{6} = \frac{37}{60} >\frac{3}{5}$$

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x)=\frac1x$ is convex for $x>0$, by Jensens inequality
$$
f\left(\frac{x_1+...+x_n}n\right)\le \frac{f(x_1)+...+f(x_n)}n,
$$
which is equivalent to the inequality of harmonic and arithmetic mean.

Now setting $x_k=n+k$ results in 
$$
\frac{n}{(n+1)+(n+2)+...+(2n)}\le \frac{\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{n+2}+...+\frac1{2n}}n
$$
or
$$
a_n\ge\frac{2n}{3n+1}=\frac23-\frac{2}{3(3n+1)}
$$
which is clearly greater than $\frac35=\frac23-\frac1{15}$ for $n=2019$.

Answer (score 1):

Cancelling the common terms:
$$
\begin{align}
a_{n+1}-a_n
&=\frac1{2n+1}+\frac1{2n+2}-\frac1{n+1}\\
&=\frac1{(2n+1)(2n+2)}\\[6pt]
&\gt0
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

It's easy and nice to prove:

**THEOREM**
$$ \sum_{k=n+1}^{2\cdot n}\frac 1k\ =
    \ \sum_{k=1}^{2\cdot n} \frac {(-1)^{k-1}}k $$

Now $\ a_{n+1}>a_n\ $ is instantly obvious.

Comment: I've promoted the above theorem over long years, including different places on the Internet. It must be well known, it should be popular but it is ... not. I discovered it in late 1950s. Where can I find this identity in print or even on the Internet. I am sure that many mathematicians of old-time knew this theorem, say, Euler, etc., and even before Euler (Gregory, Leibniz, ...). ?

Comment: Euler used $H_n=\ln(n)+\gamma+o(1)$ on the left side to find the value $\ln2=\ln(2n)-\ln(n)$ for the alternating sum on the right. This is part of his disputed but mostly correct techniques of series manipulations.

Comment: @LutzL, does this give the EXACT identity?

Comment: What do you mean with "exact"? The $o(1)$ terms converge to zero for $n\to\infty$ as the Landau notation defines, $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant, that this is a valid asymptotic form for the harmonic sums results from the considerations of Riemann sums vs. the graph of $y=1/x$.

Comment: @LutzL, the "THEOREM" from my "Answer" above is exact, it's not just o(1).

Comment: You were asking where historically this arithmetic transformation of partial sums might be found. And I said that Euler used this kind of transformation in establishing the alternating series for $\ln2$.

Comment: @LutzL, now I see, thank you! It feels so good to be connected to the past, it makes mathematics human.